# Superfluous Code Contracts suggestions

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have the following method:

```
static bool TextEquals(string text, char[] array, int start, int length)
{
    Contract.Requires(text != null);
    Contract.Requires(text.Length != length
                      || text.Length == 0
                      || (array != null && start >= 0 && start < array.Length));

    if (text.Length != length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (text[i] != array[start + i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, Code Contracts is suggesting I add the following:

```
Contracts.Requires(text.Length == 0 || array != null || start < array.Length);
Contracts.Requires(text.Length == 0 || start < 0 || start < array.Length);
```

I am not seeing the added benefit of these two additional requirements. What path(s) are covered that the already existing requirements do not cover?

In particular, I do not see the case `array == null && start < array.Length`, which would be allowed by the first suggestion.

Is there any way to remove such suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what cases the new suggestions are trying to cover, but it seems to be a result of the static analyser having a hard time with your ORed clause.

It's a good idea to keep the `Contract.Requires` expressions as simple as possible, both to help the static analyser and to make it easier for human readers.

In this example, the following set of `Requires` clauses doesn't cause any additional suggestions to be raised:

```
Contract.Requires(text != null);
Contract.Requires(array != null);
Contract.Requires(start >= 0);
Contract.Requires(start <= array.Length - length);
Contract.Requires(length >= 0);
```

These are stricter than your originals, but don't seem unreasonable for callers.

In particular, notice that `start <= array.Length - length` is needed to prevent an array overflow on `array[start + i]`; the original condition `start < array.Length` is not sufficient, and might well be the root of your problem.

As an aside, if you're willing to use LINQ, you could rewrite this method more succinctly as follows:

```
static bool TextEquals2(string text, char[] array, int start, int length)
{
    Contract.Requires(text != null);
    Contract.Requires(array != null);
    Contract.Requires(start >= 0);
    Contract.Requires(length >= 0);

    return text.SequenceEqual(array.Skip(start).Take(length));
}
```

Comment: Those are definitely better requirements anyway - I wouldn't want `TextEquals("", null, -1, -1)` to be a valid call.

Comment: I can't get Contract.Requires to do any sort of static checking based on collection length at all, the following compiles just fine for me:
<blockquote>
void foo(int[] array)
{
 Contract.Requires(0 < array.Length);
}

void bar()
{
 foo(new int[0]);
}

</blockquote>
Whereas, e.g. using 

Contracts.Requires(0 < array[0]);

will correctly fail if I try to call foo() with an array whose first element is known to be 0 at compile time.
This is with the latest version of Contracts, just downloaded. What am I missing?

Comment: Apologies for botched attempt at code formatting, not quite sure how to do it in comments!

Comment: @DylanNicholson That should work. It's probably just one of the property settings that's wrong. I suggest you raise it as a new question if it's still giving you trouble. (You can use backticks for code in comments -- see the help link on the right -- but this isn't suitable for whole blocks.)